# Wordpress activate theme error $pagenow

Tags: themes, wp-admin, child-theme, theme-options

I will start from the beging, I am migreting wp website, ant everything went fine. When I try to activate theme I get this error, also tried installing again theme , still same, other theme works fine. All plugins disabled, child theme, new wp install,nothing.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pagenow in /home/xxx/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/themefolder/inc/activation/class-tgm.php on line 79

Notice: Undefined index: action in /home/xxx/public_html/wp/wp-content/themes/themefolder/inc/activation/class-tgm.php on line 79
```

This is the part of the code giving problems:

```
}

if (is_admin() && (($pagenow == 'themes.php') || ($_GET['action'] == 'activate') || (isset($_GET['plugin']))) ) {

    if (isset($_GET['plugin']))
        {
            global $wpdb ;
        }

    $install_code =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pagenow` is a global, just like you do with `$wpdb` later on in your code you should call `global $pagenow;` before trying to use it

and `$_GET['action']` is only set when ?action= is in the url, this isnt always the case. Always make sure it is set before trying to use it:

`if( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']  == 'activate' )`